# .Net Framework 4.8.1 not installing on ARM device

Tags: windows, arm, .net-framework-version, .net-4.8

I am trying to get my application running on an ARM device, and I have the executable created but while trying to run it on the actual ARM Surface Pro i get an error.

Attempting to install from here https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-dotnet-framework-481

I get the following error

.NET Framework 4.8.1 has not been installed because:

The form specified for the subject is not one supported or known by the specified trust provider.

For more information about this problem, see the log file(below).

For information about the most current version of the .NET Framework, see Windows update

When you close this wizard you will be prompted to send a problem report to Microsoft. For more information see Microsoft Error Reporting Service http://wer.microsoft.com/responses/en-us/dcp20.aspx which doesn't seem to open anything.

```
OS Version = 10.0.22000, SP = 0.0, Platform 2 OS Description = Future OS - arm64 Unkonw Edition (ProductType=48) MSI = 5.0.22000.739 Windows servicing = 10.0.22000.826 CommandLine = C:\ce39057f3d8f36bf0ca297e30319f4\\Setup.exe /x86 /x64 /web TimeZone = Mountain Daylight Time Initial LCID = 1033 Using Simultaneous Download and Install mechanism Operation: Installing Package Name = Microsoft .NET Framework 4.8.1 Setup Package Version = 4.8.09037 User Experience Data Collection Policy: Disabled Number of applicable items: 6 C:\ce39057f3d8f36bf0ca297e30319f4\TMP16D7.tmp - Signature verification for file Windows10.0-KB5011048-arm64.cab (C:\ce39057f3d8f36bf0ca297e30319f4\TMP16D7.tmp) failed with error 0x800b0003 (The form specified for the subject is not one supported or known by the specified trust provider.) No FileHash provided. Cannot perform FileHash verification for Windows10.0-KB5011048-arm64.cab WinHttpDetectAutoProxyConfigUrl failed with error: 12180 Unable to retrieve Proxy information although WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser called succeeded C:\ce39057f3d8f36bf0ca297e30319f4\TMP16D7.tmp - Signature verification for file Windows10.0-KB5011048-arm64.cab (C:\ce39057f3d8f36bf0ca297e30319f4\TMP16D7.tmp) failed with error 0x800b0003 (The form specified for the subject is not one supported or known by the specified trust provider.) No FileHash provided. Cannot perform FileHash verification for Windows10.0-KB5011048-arm64.cab C:\ce39057f3d8f36bf0ca297e30319f4\TMP16D7.tmp - Signature verification for file Windows10.0-KB5011048-arm64.cab (C:\ce39057f3d8f36bf0ca297e30319f4\TMP16D7.tmp) failed with error 0x800b0003 (The form specified for the subject is not one supported or known by the specified trust provider.) No FileHash provided. Cannot perform FileHash verification for Windows10.0-KB5011048-arm64.cab C:\ce39057f3d8f36bf0ca297e30319f4\TMP16D7.tmp - Signature verification for file Windows10.0-KB5011048-arm64.cab (C:\ce39057f3d8f36bf0ca297e30319f4\TMP16D7.tmp) failed with error 0x800b0003 (The form specified for the subject is not one supported or known by the specified trust provider.) No FileHash provided. Cannot perform FileHash verification for Windows10.0-KB5011048-arm64.cab WinHttpDetectAutoProxyConfigUrl failed with error: 12180 Unable to retrieve Proxy information although WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser called succeeded C:\ce39057f3d8f36bf0ca297e30319f4\TMP16D7.tmp - Signature verification for file Windows10.0-KB5011048-arm64.cab (C:\ce39057f3d8f36bf0ca297e30319f4\TMP16D7.tmp) failed with error 0x800b0003 (The form specified for the subject is not one supported or known by the specified trust provider.) No FileHash provided. Cannot perform FileHash verification for Windows10.0-KB5011048-arm64.cab C:\ce39057f3d8f36bf0ca297e30319f4\TMP16D7.tmp - Signature verification for file Windows10.0-KB5011048-arm64.cab (C:\ce39057f3d8f36bf0ca297e30319f4\TMP16D7.tmp) failed with error 0x800b0003 (The form specified for the subject is not one supported or known by the specified trust provider.) No FileHash provided. Cannot perform FileHash verification for Windows10.0-KB5011048-arm64.cab C:\ce39057f3d8f36bf0ca297e30319f4\TMP16D7.tmp - Signature verification for file Windows10.0-KB5011048-arm64.cab (C:\ce39057f3d8f36bf0ca297e30319f4\TMP16D7.tmp) failed with error 0x800b0003 (The form specified for the subject is not one supported or known by the specified trust provider.) No FileHash provided. Cannot perform FileHash verification for Windows10.0-KB5011048-arm64.cab WinHttpDetectAutoProxyConfigUrl failed with error: 12180 Unable to retrieve Proxy information although WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser called succeeded C:\ce39057f3d8f36bf0ca297e30319f4\TMP16D7.tmp - Signature verification for file Windows10.0-KB5011048-arm64.cab (C:\ce39057f3d8f36bf0ca297e30319f4\TMP16D7.tmp) failed with error 0x800b0003 (The form specified for the subject is not one supported or known by the specified trust provider.) No FileHash provided. Cannot perform FileHash verification for Windows10.0-KB5011048-arm64.cab C:\ce39057f3d8f36bf0ca297e30319f4\TMP16D7.tmp - Signature verification for file Windows10.0-KB5011048-arm64.cab (C:\ce39057f3d8f36bf0ca297e30319f4\TMP16D7.tmp) failed with error 0x800b0003 (The form specified for the subject is not one supported or known by the specified trust provider.) No FileHash provided. Cannot perform FileHash verification for Windows10.0-KB5011048-arm64.cab C:\ce39057f3d8f36bf0ca297e30319f4\TMP16D7.tmp - Signature verification for file Windows10.0-KB5011048-arm64.cab (C:\ce39057f3d8f36bf0ca297e30319f4\TMP16D7.tmp) failed with error 0x800b0003 (The form specified for the subject is not one supported or known by the specified trust provider.) No FileHash provided. Cannot perform FileHash verification for Windows10.0-KB5011048-arm64.cab WinHttpDetectAutoProxyConfigUrl failed with error: 12180 Unable to retrieve Proxy information although WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser called succeeded C:\ce39057f3d8f36bf0ca297e30319f4\TMP16D7.tmp - Signature verification for file Windows10.0-KB5011048-arm64.cab (C:\ce39057f3d8f36bf0ca297e30319f4\TMP16D7.tmp) failed with error 0x800b0003 (The form specified for the subject is not one supported or known by the specified trust provider.) No FileHash provided. Cannot perform FileHash verification for Windows10.0-KB5011048-arm64.cab C:\ce39057f3d8f36bf0ca297e30319f4\TMP16D7.tmp - Signature verification for file Windows10.0-KB5011048-arm64.cab (C:\ce39057f3d8f36bf0ca297e30319f4\TMP16D7.tmp) failed with error 0x800b0003 (The form specified for the subject is not one supported or known by the specified trust provider.) No FileHash provided. Cannot perform FileHash verification for Windows10.0-KB5011048-arm64.cab RmShutdown failed with error: 351 RmShutdown failed with error: 351 Exe (C:\ce39057f3d8f36bf0ca297e30319f4\SetupUtility.exe) succeeded. Exe Log File: dd_SetupUtility.txt Exe (C:\ce39057f3d8f36bf0ca297e30319f4\SetupUtility.exe) succeeded. Exe Log File: dd_SetupUtility.txt Final Result: Installation failed with error code: (0x800B0003), "The form specified for the subject is not one supported or known by the specified trust provider. " (Elapsed time: 0 00:02:28).
     Download failed at attempt 4 of 4 for https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?prd=11324&pver=netfx&sbp=Net481Rel1&plcid=0x409&clcid=0x409&ar=09037.06&sar=amd64&o1=Windows10.0-KB5011048-arm64.cab using Http Starting download attempt 4 of 4 for https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?prd=11324&pver=netfx&sbp=Net481Rel1&plcid=0x409&clcid=0x409&ar=09037.06&sar=amd64&o1=Windows10.0-KB5011048-arm64.cab using UrlMon Action: Downloading https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?prd=11324&pver=netfx&sbp=Net481Rel1&plcid=0x409&clcid=0x409&ar=09037.06&sar=amd64&o1=Windows10.0-KB5011048-arm64.cab using UrlMon Action complete C:\c836f4eb008f659685\TMPC852.tmp: Verifying signature for Windows10.0-KB5011048-arm64.cab WinVerifyTrust failed with error: 2148204547 C:\c836f4eb008f659685\TMPC852.tmp - Signature verification for file Windows10.0-KB5011048-arm64.cab (C:\c836f4eb008f659685\TMPC852.tmp) failed with error 0x800b0003 (The form specified for the subject is not one supported or known by the specified trust provider.) Crypto API Events: EvtNext failed with error: 4317 <events>     <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">       <System>            <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-CAPI2" Guid="{5bbca4a8-b209-48dc-a8c7-b23d3e5216fb}"/>            <EventID>80</EventID>           <Version>0</Version>            <Level>4</Level>            <Task>80</Task>             <Opcode>1</Opcode>          <Keywords>0x4000000000000040</Keywords>             <TimeCreated SystemTime="2022-08-12T16:37:52.2442462Z"/>            <EventRecordID>1063</EventRecordID>             <Correlation/>          <Execution ProcessID="10472" ThreadID="1820"/>          <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-CAPI2/Operational</Channel>          <Computer>TABLET-7DHL4Q5N</Computer>            <Security UserID="S-1-5-21-3557017543-4126532510-1713417817-1001"/>         </System>       <UserData>          <WinVerifyTrustStart>
                    <EventAuxInfo ProcessName="Setup.exe"/>
                    <CorrelationAuxInfo TaskId="{C44AEB86-785A-44C1-BBFC-DA5E94B6995F}" SeqNumber="1"/>             </WinVerifyTrustStart>      </UserData>     </Event>    <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">       <System>            <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-CAPI2" Guid="{5bbca4a8-b209-48dc-a8c7-b23d3e5216fb}"/>            <EventID>81</EventID>           <Version>0</Version>            <Level>2</Level>            <Task>80</Task>             <Opcode>2</Opcode>          <Keywords>0x4000000000000040</Keywords>             <TimeCreated SystemTime="2022-08-12T16:37:52.2443847Z"/>            <EventRecordID>1064</EventRecordID>             <Correlation/>          <Execution ProcessID="10472" ThreadID="1820"/>          <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-CAPI2/Operational</Channel>          <Computer>TABLET-7DHL4Q5N</Computer>            <Security UserID="S-1-5-21-3557017543-4126532510-1713417817-1001"/>         </System>       <UserData>          <WinVerifyTrust>
                    <ActionID>{00AAC56B-CD44-11D0-8CC2-00C04FC295EE}</ActionID>
                    <UIChoice value="2">WTD_UI_NONE</UIChoice>
                    <RevocationCheck value="0"/>
                    <StateAction value="1">WTD_STATEACTION_VERIFY</StateAction>
                    <Flags value="80000040" WTD_REVOCATION_CHECK_CHAIN="true" CPD_USE_NT5_CHAIN_FLAG="true"/>
                    <FileInfo filePath="C:\c836f4eb008f659685\TMPC852.tmp" hasFileHandle="true"/>
                    <DigestInfo digestAlgorithm="" digest=""/>
                    <RegPolicySetting value="23C00" WTPF_OFFLINEOK_IND="true" WTPF_OFFLINEOK_COM="true" WTPF_OFFLINEOKNBU_IND="true" WTPF_OFFLINEOKNBU_COM="true" WTPF_IGNOREREVOCATIONONTS="true"/>
                    <StepError stepID="3" stepName="TRUSTERROR_STEP_SIP">
                        <Result value="800B0003">The form specified for the subject is not one supported or known by the specified trust provider.</Result>
                    </StepError>
                    <StepError stepID="9" stepName="TRUSTERROR_STEP_MSG_SIGNERCOUNT">
                        <Result value="800B0003">The form specified for the subject is not one supported or known by the specified trust provider.</Result>
                    </StepError>
                    <StepError stepID="32" stepName="TRUSTERROR_STEP_FINAL_OBJPROV">
                        <Result value="800B0003">The form specified for the subject is not one supported or known by the specified trust provider.</Result>
                    </StepError>
                    <StepError stepID="33" stepName="TRUSTERROR_STEP_FINAL_SIGPROV">
                        <Result value="800B0100">No signature was present in the subject.</Result>  
                    </StepError>
                    <StepError stepID="34" stepName="TRUSTERROR_STEP_FINAL_CERTPROV">
                        <Result value="800B0100">No signature was present in the subject.</Result>
                    </StepError>
                    <EventAuxInfo ProcessName="Setup.exe"/>
                    <CorrelationAuxInfo TaskId="{C44AEB86-785A-44C1-BBFC-DA5E94B6995F}" SeqNumber="2"/>
                    <Result value="800B0003">The form specified for the subject is not one supported or known by the specified trust provider.</Result>  
    </WinVerifyTrust>
</UserData>  </Event>  </events> Crypto API Events C:\c836f4eb008f659685\TMPC852.tmp Signature could not be verified for Windows10.0-KB5011048-arm64.cab No FileHash provided. Cannot perform FileHash verification for Windows10.0-KB5011048-arm64.cab Download failed at attempt 4 of 4 for https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?prd=11324&pver=netfx&sbp=Net481Rel1&plcid=0x409&clcid=0x409&ar=09037.06&sar=amd64&o1=Windows10.0-KB5011048-arm64.cab using UrlMon Action complete Action complete
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the offline installer that didn't need to download anything extra and that seemed to work. Should have tried that earlier.